# Selection of UITabBarItem loading corresponding view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `UIViewController` named "RootViewController" which contains a `UITableView` and a `UITabBar` (2 TabBarItems - Favorites and More).
When the View is being displayed, the TableView and TabBar are visible. Now I want to load an additional view when pressing the other `TabBarItem` (More). And backwards, but the tabbar should be available. (User can press Favorites)

How can this be done?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the UITabBar to be visible on more than one screen you should use a [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That controller should hold your different UIViewController.
It's wheel explain in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on how to implement that controller.

Comment: I tried this before, but I want to navigate to a new NavigationController without tabbar when selecting a entry in the tableview (rootviewcontroller).

Comment: @mybecks, at the point where you want the UITabBar, do you go deeper in your view hiearchy and not have the UITabBar? Or is it at a higher level that you don't want to see the UITabBar? And do you really want a UITabBar? You could use something like an info button type of thing or a UISegmentedControl that would control the view that is display on screen instead.

Comment: thanks for your time and helpful hints, I will use the TabBarController, its much easier instead of my prefered solution.